# Boot failure after kernel upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, zfs

I am running an ubuntu server 20.04.LTS for two years now.
Since kernel 5.4.0-62 I observe the following problem: whenever I have to update the kernel the server will not boot anymore.

EDIT: it hangs at "Loading intial ram disk". So grub ist found and I can choose from the menu.

I have to run recovery by usb stick and do the steps to fix grub:
Mount the root block device, bind /proc /sys /dev to it, chroot, run grub-install, update-grub.
Then the server boots again.

It has no effect running grub-install / update-grub on the running system.

Specifics about my setup:

- AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
- Gigabyte GA-990FXA-D3 (aged with no EFI/UEFI)
- Two SSDs as md mirror. They are partitioned. No separate boot partition.
- /root partition is ext4.
- /swap partition
- Partition for zfs mirror. But not booting from it.
- two more SSDs completely dedicated to zfs
- two Hdds with zfs as backup

I guess it has something to do with dkms and zfs but I cannot figure out how to analyze the error.
Since it is my productive home server with several VMs and services on it I cannot permanently reboot it.

Result of:

```
sudo fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | egrep "Disk /|/dev/" | sed "s#^/dev/#Part /dev/#" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://' | xargs -n1 -IX sudo sh -c "hexdump -v -s 0x80 -n  2 -e '2/1 \"%x\" \"\\n\"' X | xargs -n1 -IY sh -c \"case  \"Y\" in '48b4') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.96 ;; 'aa75' | '5272') echo X: GRUB Legacy ;; '7c3c') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.97 oder v1.98 ;; '020') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.99 ;; *) echo X: Kein GRUB Y ;; esac\""
```

Output:

```
/dev/loop0: Kein GRUB 15d
/dev/loop1: Kein GRUB 15d
/dev/loop2: Kein GRUB fe5d
/dev/loop3: Kein GRUB 595d
/dev/loop4: Kein GRUB 595d
/dev/loop5: Kein GRUB ff5d
/dev/sdc: GRUB 2 v1.99
/dev/sdc1: Kein GRUB ebf
/dev/sdc2: Kein GRUB b12f
/dev/sdc3: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sde: GRUB 2 v1.99
/dev/sde1: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sde9: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sdd: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sdd1: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sdd9: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sda: GRUB 2 v1.99
/dev/sda1: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sda2: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sda3: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sdb: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sdb1: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sdb9: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/md1: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/md0: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sdf: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sdf1: Kein GRUB 00
/dev/sdf9: Kein GRUB 415e
```

EDIT:
New Info (28.01.22) as the problem is still there. I unplugged boot disks just keeping two backup disks with zfs on it. Then I installed a fresh SSD and installed a minimal Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS server on it and also this one does not boot.

Meanwhile I have four kernel versions installed: 5.4.0-96 to -89. I have to try them one by one including the recovery modes until I get one running, usually the recovery ones. All others stop either at "Loading initial ram disk" or you see the startup for a second, then the display goes black. I know it does not further boot because it doesnt react to ping later.

How can I find out what goes wrong here?

Comment: Please can you add;   this `sudo fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | egrep "Disk /|/dev/" | sed "s#^/dev/#Part /dev/#" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://' | xargs -n1 -IX sudo sh -c "hexdump -v -s 0x80 -n  2 -e '2/1 \"%x\" \"\\n\"' X | xargs -n1 -IY sh -c \"case  \"Y\" in '48b4') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.96 ;; 'aa75' | '5272') echo X: GRUB Legacy ;; '7c3c') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.97 oder v1.98 ;; '020') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.99 ;; *) echo X: Kein GRUB Y ;; esac\""` will show you if grub is installt somewhere else besides /dev/sda.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest comparing which partition is mounted under `/boot/grub` on the running system and when you successfully run `update-grub` within the chroot. It sounds as if this differs (and I've faced this problem myself in the past).

Comment: In both cases /dev/sda2 and /dev/sdc2 make up /dev/md1 and /dev/md127 on the recovery. So I install grub to /dev/sda and /dev/sdc. Grub also starts, the system hangs on "Loading initial ram disk". So I get the menu.